# How can I change the location of the .minecraft directory in the 2.1 Launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I don't want to have the `.minecraft` folder in the `%APPDATA%` folder. How can I move it somewhere else?

I'm using Launcher version 2.1, that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Minecraft Launcher has a couple of [Command Line parameters](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_launcher#Command_line_usage) that you can use for changing the behavior of it. The `--workDir` parameter allows you to specify the location of the .minecraft folder.

To use this parameter, you can create a batch file that will open the Launcher and change the folder. You can just copy-paste the following snippet into notepad and save it as Launch.bat on the same folder as the Minecraft Launcher. You need to replace FOLDER with the location of the folder that you want to use.

```
@echo off
start MinecraftLauncher.exe --workDir "FOLDER"
```

Then, just open Launch.bat to open the Launcher and use the specified folder.

Answer (score 1):

From a [suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/320892):

> There is even a simpler version to do the same. Just right-click your Minecraft shortcut, click Properties and add in "Target" the line --workDir "FOLDER".

Answer (score 0):

Move the .minecraft folder to where you want it to be. Then, open your launcher and go into the Installations tab, click on the profile you play on, click on browse button under Game Directory, and select the .minecraft from the directory you moved it to.

Comment: This changes the location of the saved data for the specific version (logs, resource packs, worlds and options to be specific), not the entire .minecraft folder.