# How do I change Minecraft Java for Linux game instance directory location?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, linux

NOTE: The system I am talking about is Linux which has different file system from Windows, meaning %APPDATA%/.minecraft is non-existent in Linux

So I have installed [Pop!_OS](https://pop.system76.com/) to learn linux and I have game save from Windows 10 stored in a external drive following this [page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364672/how-can-i-change-the-location-of-the-minecraft-directory-in-the-2-1-launcher). Now that I have installed Minecraft from [official site](https://www.minecraft.net/download), how do I tell the Minecraft in Linux where to look for the game saves and account information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a symbolic link (symlink) with command `ln -s /data/on/windows/drive ~/.minecraft`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't really work out what the problem was. Here are some instructions I quickly created and tested:

Download https://launcher.mojang.com/download/Minecraft.tar.gz and extract it.

In the newly created folder create a script named `minecraft.sh`, or whatever you prefer, with the following contents:

```
chmod +x minecraft-launcher # Just in case
./minecraft-launcher --workDir=`readlink -f HERE` # Use readlink to resolve absolute path
```

Replace `HERE` with where you want the portable installation to be located.

When you execute this script, it should run the launcher and game in the specified directory.

For ease of use, you can add it to your menu using "menulibre".

Install menulibre (`sudo apt install menulibre`), and open it (search for "Menu Editor" in applications).

Create a new menu entry that executes the script, and if you want a fancy icon, you can add one easily.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I attempted to do what you said and everything went well until the part when I execute the manually created .sh file. From the console I see multiple lines of `WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1262)] The GPU process has crashed 9 time(s)` and the last line is `FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.`. Then I tried starting Minecraft again normally and it launched successfully, just didn't do what I wanted it to do. so ummmm yes any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Ubuntu 21.10. It must be something to do launching it from the terminal. Maybe try double clicking the script.